# SwiftUI Animations acting weird, or I don't know how to use them

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-animation

I have set up a basic view with just a Slider and a Button in a List, for some reason, the animation with a duration of 10 seconds happens pretty much instantly, as a matter of fact, no matter what I put inside the `withAnimation` the animation always looks the same.

Code:

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct TestView: View {
    @State private var value = 5.0
    
    var body: some View {
        List {
            Slider(
                value: $value,
                in: 0...10
            ) {
            } minimumValueLabel: {
                Text("0")
            } maximumValueLabel: {
                Text("10")
            }
            Button("Button") {
                withAnimation(.easeInOut(duration: 10)) {
                    value += 3
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct TestView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        TestView()
    }
}
```

Implicit animations don't seem to work either, but I think I just don't know how Swift animations work, any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The implementation of the animated value change is correct.

You can verify this by inserting a custom view (I placed mine between the slider and the button & used a spring animation). Something like this:

```
Color.blue
    .frame(width: value * 10, height: 20)
```

[image]

Which means that the "problem" is with SwiftUI's `Slider`, which seems that it can only use two modes: an immediate change of value & an internally predefined animation (you can notice that if you remove the animation).

Comment: Ah that's awesome, thank you very much!